# Failing to install cvxpy.py on Ubuntu 22.04.3 LTS, on Zynq UltraScale+ MPSoC based SOM ARM Cortex-A53 4 core processor

Tags: ubuntu, python, amd, arm64, fpga

I was barely able after much effort to get this to install 9 or so months ago, now it doesn't install on the same platform with a new update/upgrade. Here's the software version info:

```
ubuntu@BDv4-10031:~$ lsb_release -a
No LSB modules are available.
Distributor ID: Ubuntu
Description:    Ubuntu 22.04.3 LTS
Release:        22.04
Codename:       jammy
ubuntu@BDv4-10031:~$
```

After installing the long list of imports and dependencies and successfully navigating those in the successful past:

```
sudo apt-get -y install cmake libglpk-dev
sudo pip3 install meson pytest jupyter pandas numpy pvlib matplotlib scikit-learn
sudo pip3 install tensorflow gym cvxpy cvxpyanalyzer vpython
sudo pip3 install scip scipy cylp cbc ecos glpk copt cvxopt clarabel glop cplex  xpress
sudo updatedb
# cd to the directory /site-packages/cvxpy/
pytest
```

And I did try this without sudo pip3, makes no difference, the problem is package versioning.

I got this in retrying after cvxpy install failed:

```
ubuntu@BDv4-10031:~$ sudo pip3 install cvxpy
Collecting cvxpy
  Using cached cvxpy-1.4.1-cp310-cp310-manylinux_2_17_aarch64.manylinux2014_aarch64.whl (1.1 MB)
Collecting ecos>=2
  Using cached ecos-2.0.12.tar.gz (142 kB)
  Installing build dependencies ... done
  Getting requirements to build wheel ... done
  Preparing metadata (pyproject.toml) ... done
Requirement already satisfied: numpy>=1.15 in /usr/local/lib/python3.10/dist-packages (from cvxpy) (1.26.2)
Collecting osqp>=0.6.2
  Using cached osqp-0.6.3-cp310-cp310-manylinux_2_17_aarch64.manylinux2014_aarch64.whl (294 kB)
Collecting scipy>=1.1.0
  Using cached scipy-1.11.4-cp310-cp310-manylinux_2_17_aarch64.manylinux2014_aarch64.whl (32.9 MB)
Requirement already satisfied: pybind11 in /usr/lib/python3/dist-packages (from cvxpy) (2.9.1)
Collecting clarabel>=0.5.0
  Using cached clarabel-0.6.0-cp37-abi3-manylinux_2_17_aarch64.manylinux2014_aarch64.whl (1.4 MB)
Collecting scs>=3.0
  Using cached scs-3.2.4.tar.gz (1.5 MB)
  Installing build dependencies ... done
  Getting requirements to build wheel ... done
  Installing backend dependencies ... done
  Preparing metadata (pyproject.toml) ... error
  error: subprocess-exited-with-error
  
  �� Preparing metadata (pyproject.toml) did not run successfully.
  ��� exit code: 1
  ������> [2 lines of output]
      
      ('\x1b[31m',)meson-python: error: Could not find ninja version 1.8.2 or newer.
      [end of output]
  
  note: This error originates from a subprocess, and is likely not a problem with pip.
error: metadata-generation-failed

�� Encountered error while generating package metadata.
������> See above for output.

note: This is an issue with the package mentioned above, not pip.
hint: See above for details.
```

---

Then I tried to install the missing meson:

```
ubuntu@BDv4-10031:~$ sudo pip3 install meson-python-1.8.2
ERROR: Could not find a version that satisfies the requirement meson-python-1.8.2 (from versions: none)
ERROR: No matching distribution found for meson-python-1.8.2
ubuntu@BDv4-10031:~$ sudo apt install meson ninja-build
Reading package lists... Done
Building dependency tree... Done
Reading state information... Done
The following packages were automatically installed and are no longer required:
  libflashrom1 libftdi1-2
Use 'sudo apt autoremove' to remove them.
The following NEW packages will be installed:
  meson ninja-build
0 upgraded, 2 newly installed, 0 to remove and 6 not upgraded.
Need to get 624 kB of archives.
After this operation, 3675 kB of additional disk space will be used.
Get:1 http://ports.ubuntu.com/ubuntu-ports jammy/universe arm64 ninja-build arm64 1.10.1-1 [105 kB]
Get:2 http://ports.ubuntu.com/ubuntu-ports jammy/universe arm64 meson all 0.61.2-1 [519 kB]
Fetched 624 kB in 1s (474 kB/s)
Selecting previously unselected package ninja-build.
(Reading database ... 275117 files and directories currently installed.)
Preparing to unpack .../ninja-build_1.10.1-1_arm64.deb ...
Unpacking ninja-build (1.10.1-1) ...
Selecting previously unselected package meson.
Preparing to unpack .../meson_0.61.2-1_all.deb ...
Unpacking meson (0.61.2-1) ...
Setting up ninja-build (1.10.1-1) ...
Setting up meson (0.61.2-1) ...
Processing triggers for man-db (2.10.2-1) ...
Scanning processes...                                                                                                                                                                                                                  
Scanning processor microcode...                                                                                                                                                                                                        
Scanning linux images...                                                                                                                                                                                                               

Running kernel seems to be up-to-date.

Failed to check for processor microcode upgrades.

No services need to be restarted.

No containers need to be restarted.

No user sessions are running outdated binaries.

No VM guests are running outdated hypervisor (qemu) binaries on this host.
```

---

Now retried installing cvxpy.py:

```
ubuntu@BDv4-10031:~$ sudo pip3 install cvxpy
Collecting cvxpy
  Using cached cvxpy-1.4.1-cp310-cp310-manylinux_2_17_aarch64.manylinux2014_aarch64.whl (1.1 MB)
Requirement already satisfied: pybind11 in /usr/lib/python3/dist-packages (from cvxpy) (2.9.1)
Collecting scipy>=1.1.0
  Using cached scipy-1.11.4-cp310-cp310-manylinux_2_17_aarch64.manylinux2014_aarch64.whl (32.9 MB)
Collecting scs>=3.0
  Using cached scs-3.2.4.tar.gz (1.5 MB)
  Installing build dependencies ... done
  Getting requirements to build wheel ... done
  Installing backend dependencies ... done
  Preparing metadata (pyproject.toml) ... error
  error: subprocess-exited-with-error
  
  �� Preparing metadata (pyproject.toml) did not run successfully.
  ��� exit code: 1
  ������> [3 lines of output]
      
      ('\x1b[31m',)meson-python: error: Could not find meson version 0.63.3 or newer, found 0.61.2
      ('\x1b[31m',)meson-python: error: .
      [end of output]
  
  note: This error originates from a subprocess, and is likely not a problem with pip.
error: metadata-generation-failed

�� Encountered error while generating package metadata.
������> See above for output.

note: This is an issue with the package mentioned above, not pip.
hint: See above for details.
ubuntu@BDv4-10031:~$ sudo pip3 uninstall meson
Found existing installation: meson 1.3.0
Uninstalling meson-1.3.0:
  Would remove:
    /usr/local/bin/meson
    /usr/local/lib/python3.10/dist-packages/meson-1.3.0.dist-info/*
    /usr/local/lib/python3.10/dist-packages/mesonbuild/*
    /usr/local/share/man/man1/meson.1
    /usr/local/share/polkit-1/actions/com.mesonbuild.install.policy
Proceed (Y/n)? y
  Successfully uninstalled meson-1.3.0
WARNING: Running pip as the 'root' user can result in broken permissions and conflicting behaviour with the system package manager. It is recommended to use a virtual environment instead: https://pip.pypa.io/warnings/venv
```

---

Tried uninstalling meson and reinstalling cvxpi, same error.

My worry is that the KV260 platform with its dependence on petalinux for getting FPGA IP blocks to run, is being deprecated in the new, sleek petalinux-free KR260 platform and when things get harder to install on Ubuntu, it raises my platform end-of-life fears.

Answer (score 0):

Your posted output shows different Python installs (`/usr/local/lib/python3.10` and `/usr/lib/python3`) and I am not quite sure which version you are using to install these modules.  If the following advice does not help, you should post more information about your Python environment.

The first problem shown in your post:  `sudo pip3 install cvxpy` produced the error `Could not find ninja version 1.8.2 or newer` while trying to build `scs-3.2.4`.  You attempted to fix this error with `sudo pip3 install meson-python-1.8.2` which causes an error because there is no version 1.8.2 of `meson-python` available to `pip`.

The command that eventually progressed further: `sudo apt install meson ninja-build` installed `ninja-1.10.1`, which satisfies the previous error, and `meson-0.61.2`.  Unfortunately, the version of `scs` that is trying to build requires `meson-0.63.3`.  Ubuntu 22.04 does not package a newer version of `meson`.

It does appear that due to your CPU, there are no pre-built versions of `scs` so it would need to be built on your machine.  You could try to install an older version of `scs` that does not require the newer version of meson:  `sudo pip install scs==3.2.0` (or any previous version that can satisfy `scs>=3.0`) and if that succeeds you should get further with installing `cvxpy`.

Not related to your current issue, but I would recommend to do all this work within Python virtual environments (`python -m venv $YOUR_NEW_PYTHON_ENV`) so as not to pollute the system Python environments.